# Why can not I get the Routes of Data in Service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to be able to dynamically get route information in the Service , but found that data are empty (for example, as the data property ..), but it can be obtained full data from the Component

[live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzKSyceVuS2XoINUKid4?p=preview)

```js
// AppRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/child', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'child',
    component: ChildComponent,
    data: {
      pageName: 'child page!!'
    }
  },
];
========================
// ChildComponent
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private childService: ChildService
  ) { 

  }

  getPageName() {    
    this.activateRoute.data
      .subscribe(val => console.log('child_component_pageName:', val['pageName']));
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    // has Data
    this.getPageName();
   // empty 
   this.childService.getPageName();
   // empty
   this.childService.getPageNameBySnapshot();

   /*
   output:
   ---
   child_component_pageName: child page!!
   child_service_pageName: undefined
   child_service_snapshot_pageName: undefined
   */
  }

}

==================================
// ChildService
@Injectable()
export class ChildService {
    constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    getPageName() {
        this.activateRoute.data
        .subscribe(val => console.log('child_service_pageName:', val['pageName']));
    }

    getPageNameBySnapshot() {
         console.log('child_service_snapshot_pageName:', this.activateRoute.snapshot.data['pageName']);
    }
}
```

> my english is not good, if the grammar is not right , please let me know.

Comment: In the service use `activatedRoute.snapshot.data["pageName"]` and it should work

Comment: The snapshot does not work and I've updated it to live example

Comment: What exactly do you want? `val['pageName']` links to your route params. So if you're using something like `/some/random/route/:pageName` in your router, `val['pageName']` will get the specific pageName.

Comment: I would like to obtain PagName directly from Service, not from the Compoent's constructor, so that Server can be reused